# How to add users in HARAKA by fetching data from Database

Tags: database, node.js

I am new in node.js field I wanted to create users in haraka by fetching data from database . what i know that for creating users you have to add manually in auth_flat_file.ini 
Could anyone please guide me how to create users by fething data from database

Answer (score 0):

You can check this module: https://github.com/jcowgar/haraka-plugins

Work with mysql. Exactly what you ask for...